# MySQL Count, Sum, and then Divide

Tags: mysql

I have looked through many of the posts on this forum and others, and I can't find a solution that is similar to what I need.

I wrote a couple simple queries so that we could have some financial statistical information from our database... This one however, I just can't seem to nail down...

From this query, I get our TotalRevenue from each InsuranceCarrier and NumberOfOrders they have placed with us... but on this particular query, I need it to divide the TotalRevenue by the NumberOfOrders, and give an AverageTicket to "ORDER BY" Otherwise the echo'd list isn't in the correct order, even though I can make the division calculations post query...

Here's my query...

```
SELECT OrderTickets.InsuranceCarrierID, 
       COUNT(OrderTickets.OrderTicketPayoutAmount) as NumberOfOrders, 
       SUM(OrderTickets.OrderTicketPayoutAmount) as TotalRevenue, 
       InsuranceCarriers.InsuranceCarrier 
  FROM OrderTickets
  LEFT JOIN InsuranceCarriers 
          ON OrderTickets.InsuranceCarrierID = InsuranceCarriers.InsuranceCarrierID 
 GROUP BY OrderTickets.InsuranceCarrierID
 ORDER BY TotalRevenue DESC
```

I have tried a few alterations, but with no success, I didn't post it because it doesn't work, but if anyone wants to see my attempts, I will gladly post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AVG()` like so:

```
SELECT OrderTickets.InsuranceCarrierID, 
       COUNT(OrderTickets.OrderTicketPayoutAmount) as NumberOfOrders, 
       SUM(OrderTickets.OrderTicketPayoutAmount) as TotalRevenue, 
       AVG(OrderTickets.OrderTicketPayoutAmount) as AverageRevenue, 
       InsuranceCarriers.InsuranceCarrier 
  FROM OrderTickets
  LEFT JOIN InsuranceCarriers 
          ON OrderTickets.InsuranceCarrierID = InsuranceCarriers.InsuranceCarrierID 
 GROUP BY OrderTickets.InsuranceCarrierID
 ORDER BY AverageRevenue DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

using temp table you will be able to do it easily .

get total revenue , carrier and number of orders  and put it in a temp table and in next step do calculation

i think it will be better option than trying a single complex query !!!!

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm